# Grepl matching for multiple conditions including 'and' and 'or' conditions

Tags: r, contains, grepl

My dataframe is as follows

```
df <- data.frame(c("Utility grid", "Grid connection", "Grid", "", "", "Dry-cell-torch", "Solar", ""), c("solar", "", "", "", "", "", "Dry-cell-torch", ""), c("", "fan", "TV", "", "Utility grid connection", "", "", "Unreachable"), c("", "radio", "", "", "", "", "", "")) 
colnames(df) <- c(paste("de_", 1:4, sep=""))
```

I want to append a 5th column "de" to this dataframe with the following conditions -

- Condition 1. If all rows are blank such as row 4, "de" should be 0.
- Condition 2. If only of the 4 rows is non-blank, and that value is either 'contains' "grid" without being case sensitive, or is "Unreachable", or is "Dry-cell-torch", then "de" should be 0.
- Condition 3. Else "de" should be 1

The desired "de" should be

```
df$de <- (c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0))
```

Please note my original dataframe is 600 rows and 45 columns. I am just putting a subset here but this subset illustrates the exhaustive conditions I want to accomplish.

So I tried the following regex using grepl (adapted from a solution given by one of you here on stackoverflow in a different but similar problem) -

```
df$de <- (!grepl("grid|Unreachable|Dry-cell-torch|^$", 
                  apply(df,1,paste, collapse=""), ignore.case=TRUE))+0L
```

This works except in the case where let's say in row 1, where in 1 column I have "Utility grid", and in second I have "solar", it gives me de as 0 while I need 1. I understand the problem - which is that if one of grid, unreachable etc are present this should be combined with an 'and' condition of all other cells in same row should be blank but I am unable to figure how to implement this

I appreciate your help!

Comment: you say a lot row instead of columns, can you clean your question ?

Comment: I'm confused on what you are looking for with condition 2. If you are checking that any of the 4 columns have values, and then checking the values to see if they are either "Unreachable" or "Dry-cell-torch" or contain "grid". Then every de value would be 0 for your example.

Comment: Moody, that's because I intent it to be rows instead of columns. So I want the R code to go through each row across the 4 columns, and check for the 3 conditions listed, and accordingly assign a value to de.      Matt, in condition 2, if any of the columns are either "Unreachable" or "Dry-cell-torch" or contain "grid" AND if a column has a non-blank value apart from these values, de should be 1 else de should 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider splitting up the condition explicitly:

```
f <- function(x) {
  if ( all(x == '') ) 0
  else if ( sum(x != '') == 1 ) {
    if ( grepl('grid', tolower(x[x != ''])) |
         (x[x != ''] %in% c('Unreachable', 'Dry-cell-torch')) ) 0
    else 1
  } 
  else 1
}
```

And then use apply `apply(df, 1, f)`

I seem to get the vector you want:

```
> apply(df, 1, f)
[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

**Update:**

Another argument could be used to index the specific columns you want within f. Note that this is not a robust implementation -- setting the wrong columns will break it.

```
f <- function(x, columns) {

  y <- x[columns]

  if ( all(y == '') ) 0
  else if ( sum(y != '') == 1 ) {
    if ( grepl('grid', tolower(y[y != ''])) |
         (y[y != ''] %in% c('Unreachable', 'Dry-cell-torch')) ) 0
    else 1
  } 
  else 1
}
```

And then use apply `apply(df, 1, f, columns = 1:4)`. Just replace 1:4 with the columns you want.

**Update 2:**

Not sure if I entirely understand your latest comment, but if you want to consider more than one "special" cell, you could consider the following structure (although I'm not sure if it would be much more "elegant" than what you have tried):

```
f <- function(x, columns) {

  y <- x[columns]

  n.not.blank <- sum( y != '' )
  special <- c('Unreachable', 'Dry-cell-torch')
  n.special <- sum( grepl('grid', tolower(y)) | (y %in% special) )

  if (n.not.blank == 0) 0
  else if (n.not.blank == n.special) 0
  else 1

}
```

And then use apply as before.

Comment: Thanks Ssokolen! This is a great solution. My dataframe is 45 columns and 600 rows. The 4 columns in question are columns 33:36 in terms of order of columns. Can this solution be adapted to a subset of columns?

Comment: @user3816784 Sure, there are a couple of ways to do it. You could simply index x from within the function or add a new argument to do it in a more general fashion. I'll edit my answer with the changes.

Comment: Thanks Ssokolen! I appreciate you giving the edited answer. The code works fine except in one scenario - where two columns are non-empty and one has let's say contains "grid" and the other is "unreachable", and the others are blank. In order for de to be 1, I need at least one non-blank column which does not contain grid, and is not unreachable and dry-cell-torch. I can do this by writing several if else statements for each column but was wondering if there is a more elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: @user3816784 I'm not sure if you're notified when I make an edit to the answer, but see the newest update.

Comment: Thanks Ssokolen! Your solution is very intuitive and fits in perfectly. Apologies for acknowledging this so late. I have been traveling and just getting back to the code. I have accepted your solution as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. I set a default value of 1, then set the value to zero if there's only blanks, or if there's only blank except for one, and that this exceptional value fits your regex.

```
df <- data.frame(c("Utility grid", "Grid connection", "Grid", "", "", "Dry-cell-torch", "Solar", ""), c("solar", "", "", "", "", "", "Dry-cell-torch", ""), c("", "fan", "TV", "", "Utility grid connection", "", "", "Unreachable"), c("", "radio", "", "", "", "", "", "")) 
colnames(df) <- c(paste("de_", 1:4, sep=""))
df$de <- 1 # default value
blank_rows <- apply(df,1,function(row){sum(row == "")==ncol(df)-1})
regex_rows <- apply(df,1,function(row){sum(row == "")==ncol(df)-2 & any(grepl("grid|Unreachable|Dry-cell-torch|^$", row,ignore.case = TRUE))})
df$de[blank_rows | regex_rows] <- 0

# de_1           de_2                    de_3  de_4 de
# 1    Utility grid          solar                                1
# 2 Grid connection                                    fan radio  1
# 3            Grid                                     TV        1
# 4                                                               0
# 5                                Utility grid connection        0
# 6  Dry-cell-torch                                               0
# 7           Solar Dry-cell-torch                                1
# 8                                            Unreachable        0
```

Comment: Thanks! This really works and I can see how its helpful to break the conditions in different lines of code. I am trying to slowly understand the code for blank_rows and regex_rows and had the following questions (I am still a beginner!). Q1 - you assigned a function inside apply, but you are not calling this function with any argument anywhere? How is it really working.

Comment: Q2  - in the past of code "sum(row == "")==ncol(df)-1" on the LHS you are assigning an object, but this object is also performing an operation how is that? I mean the object on the LHS just accepts the operation on the RHS right, how are operations happening simultaneously on both sides of "<-". Q3 - can you please break down the code for regex_rows for me. I appreciate your help - and apologize for my beginner like questions

Comment: The 2 first arguments of apply mean that we're going to take every row of df, and pass it as an argument to the function that you put in the 3rd argument.  You can use a base function such as sum or a function you defined elsewhere, or as I did here you can define a new function on the spot

Comment: `row == "" ` returns and array of booleans, taking the sum of them returns the count of true values (blank values here)

Comment: The row is blank if this amount is equal to the number of columns in your df, except for the `de` column that I've added, so `ncol(df)-1`

Comment: `==` is NOT an assignment operator, make sure you understand that :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :-) This helps

Comment: You're welcome, if you're satisfied by the answer please consider validating it.

Comment: Your solution is very elegant, thank you! I realized I can only accept one solution as an answer. I have accepted the above code which I found more easy to read as a beginner.